# bash function to greet user differently based on number of arguments given

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

Hi I'm new to bash but I wanted to create a function that greeted a user differently based on the number of arguments they gave.

When I try it out I get this error:
hello.sh:8: parse error near `}'

I was wondering what I was doing wrong here. however this is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
greet() {
  if [["$#" -eq 1]]; then
  echo hello, $1

  else
  echo single argument only
}
```

I wanted it to say hello if a user entered their name but say single argument only if a user entered a string separated by a space.
for example

```
$greet John
hello, John
$greet John smith
single argument only
```

would the issue be a part of my if statement?

Comment: While the error message in the duplicate isn't identical, the underlying reason and the fix are.

Comment: Thank you, I figured out what I did wrong was not including fi at the end of my if else statement

Comment: The syntax of `[[ ... ]]` without blanks was also incorrect.

Comment: It also seems that your error is actually from zsh, and not Bash.